# click event without open a new tab in selenium

Tags: selenium, tabs, click, webdriver

I'm making a bot that opens a new tab and works with some tabs.

The code I use for opening a new tab is,

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL +"t");
```

OK. That works. It opens a new tab. Later I need to click an "a" element, and I have this code:

```
String next_button_path = "#page_next";
        WebElement next_button = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(next_button_path));
        Actions next_page = new Actions(driver);
        next_page.click(next_button).perform();
```

But, it opens a new tab instead of just click. It looks like it's still pressed the "control" button...

What I'm doing wrong? It's possible to click an element like a normal click?

Comment: What happens if you do it manually?

Comment: What do you mean with "manually"?

Comment: Can you test this scenario manually?

Comment: Do you mean without using the bot?

Comment: Yes without using anything

Comment: Without the bot (doing it myself) it works. If I use the bot without opening a new tab it works. But it crashes when I open the new tab. I think the problem is that the bot still press the "control" key... but I don't know why...

Comment: What is the browser, browser version, and OS the browser runs in?

Comment: I'm using my Firefox Profile (version 33.1) on windows 7 professional

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String next_button_path = "#page_next";
WebElement next_button = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(next_button_path));
actions.moveToElement(next_button);
actions.click();
actions.perform();
```

Or

```
WebElement next_button = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#page_next"));
next_button.click();
```

Comment: I tried both options: The first one makes the same error (it open a new tab) and the second one didn't click the button. That's so strange.

Comment: Can you provide your html and possibly attach the screenshot?

Comment: This is the screenshot:http://i.imgur.com/oQv04qK.png I search on tab "Inventario actual" and then I use the code you saw (opening tab code I mean) The HTML element I click is this: <a href="javascript:InvNextPage();" id="page_next" class="pagecntrl_element"> &gt; </a>